# Windows servce won't run if no user logged into server

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I created a windows service that's basically a file watcher that wont run unless a user is logged into the machine its on.

The service is running on a Windows Server 2003 machine. It is designed to listen for excel files in a folder. When there is a excel file, it starts to send some information to a web service. When it's done, it copies the processed file to a archive folder.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards
Baris

Comment: no, nobody can help you. You got to describe problem better, give us some code, does your service interact with desktop, user acc under your service is running etc

Comment: Which user account is the service running under? What are error messages you're getting? What's in the Windows event log?

Comment: What is your question?  Do you mean (1) the service is supposed to only run when a user is logged on, and you need to know how to do that; or (2) the service is supposed to run when nobody is logged on, but doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Run it as a user that has rights to log on as service on the machine. Make sure this user has an access to the directory you watch.

Answer (score 0):

What i always do in a scenario like that is give the user logon as batch job and logon as a service rights. 
 1 of these 2 will most likely fix your problem.
You can configure this in the local group policy editor as described [here](http://kbase.gfi.com/showarticle.asp?id=KBID003504)
Be aware though that if your computer is in a domain it is possible that the group policy gets pushed to the server every 15 mins so you might have to talk to a system admin to get things sorted.

Answer (score 0):

When you actually only want to run when someone is logged in, do not use a service but an autostart application in that case.

If you have to be a service because of account privileges, the service may detect the current logins itself, but you may combine a service with a client (autostart) application that connects to the service. That way, you can also show tray incos, status informations and enable the user to control your service using the client application.
Using Win7 and higher, services themselves (running in session 0) can no longer display UI interactions on the user's desktop.

Keep in mind that there may be multiple users logged in on current operating systems...

Comment: oh, I would really like why I got this downvote so I could enhance my answer (or even delete, if I misunderstood something...)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but having both a service and an autostart application is unnecessary.  If you've got a service, it can detect logins itself.

Comment: I suspect that the OP may be wanting his service to work when nobody is logged on, and asking why it doesn't.  Your interpretation is equally valid, though, so I've asked him to clarify.  +1 for spotting the ambiguity!

Comment: @arx: The combination of service an autostart application enables you to have such things as tray icons with status or control functions. You are absolutely right, the service can detect the logins itself, I was already thinking about the status part meaning "hello service, please send status updates to me using [whatever protocol]" when writing about the login info. updated my text to reflect that part better